# Horizontal Scrolling of Background Image

Tags: css

I have a div with multiple elements inside it that span farther than the width of the parent div. I set overflow-x to scroll, and background-attachment to scroll as well, but when I scroll side to side the background image remains fixed

Here's a link to the page: http://okcomputerstl.com/K9_Athletic_Club/services.html
The brick background is what I would like to scroll

Here's the css

```
.framecontain {
    width: 979px;
    height: 490px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-image: url(../graphics/services/brickbg.png);
}

.services .textbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    width: 395px;
    height: 358px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url(../graphics/services/frame.png);
}

.services .one {
    left: 64px;
}

.services .two {
    left: 508px;
}

.services .three {
    left: 953px;
}

.services .four {
    left: 1388px;
}

.services .five {
    left: 1826px;
}
```

Comment: I've found that overflow-x sucks. It won't happen if you use a full `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: is there a better way to paste this css?

Comment: @HenryWinn I've added it to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you'll have to wrap your brick wall container in another div to achieve this.

```
<div id="container">  <!-- div having the scrollbar-->
  <div id="bricks"></div> <!-- div having the background-->
</div>
```